# i am unable to creat uptime check for cloud run service using terraform can someone please provide code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, uptime

what are the labels that i should add ( project id, sevrice name,location i added that but gives error)
https_check or http_check?
Error: Error creating UptimeCheckConfig: googleapi: Error 400: Error confirming monitored resource:
│ type:      "cloud_run_service"

terraform code  for uptime check of cloud run

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: what happens if you use cloud_run_revision as monitored resource? https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_cloud_run_revision